# jquery hide() not working on div with absolute position

Tags: jquery

For some reason I can't manage to get this to work and I can't manage to figure out why. It seems fairly simple just to .hide() a div but it doesn't seem to work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#sideboxTrackingInformation').hide();
    });
```

});

See here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bislewl/73f2d3ut/4/

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your demo.

Comment: To provide context to the question, I would have also added the version of jQuery you are using in your document along with the code already presented.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to include jQuery in your demo. It now works here:

https://jsfiddle.net/73f2d3ut/10/

Just add

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

or whichever version you prefer.

---

**Amendment**: @charlietfl and I have uncovered something strange between Chrome and FF. In Chrome and IE it seems that `event` available to your function without it being explicitly passed in. See the screen shot below:

[image]

However, in FF this same code causes an error. To be on the safe side, also take into consideration the advice of @charlietfl and change your function like this:

```
$("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function (event) {...
```

**Update:** I've opened up a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159017/why-is-event-available-in-this-anonymous-function-in-chrome-but-not-ff/30159029#30159029), and the response it that IE and Chrome have a global `event` object, whereas FF does not.

Comment: bit more to it than toggling a dropdown in fiddle ... your demo still throws error

Comment: @charlietfl "It seems fairly simple just to .hide() a div but it doesn't seem to work" - the OP wishes to hide a div on a click. With jQuery included, it now does that. Anything else is academic. Retract your downvote.

Comment: Would you kindly load my fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/73f2d3ut/9/? Show me how it is not working. Event is passed in fine.

Comment: ReferenceError: event is not defined...it's not there

Comment: not sure where chomr is getting the event from...fails in other browsers though because it isn't passed to function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77471/discussion-between-drakes-and-charlietfl).

Comment: I would actually consider that a chrome bug since convention has always been to pass event in

Answer (score 1):

You haven't passed the `event` object to the click handler.

This  causes error using `event.preventdefault()` ... look in browser dev tools console

Change:

```
 $("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function () {...
```

To

```
$("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function (event) {...
```

EDIT: note of interest...seems that chrome doesn't care if event is passed in or not whereas other browsers do

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nw6j8u5c/)**</kbd>

Comment: The error is caused by not included jQuery. How have you addressed that in your answer?

Comment: @Drakes a forgotten toggle in a fiddle is not the same as fixing the underlying problem in the code

Comment: Agreed. We've uncovered a bug, it seems.

Comment: I've opened a question on this and got a response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30159017/why-is-event-available-in-this-anonymous-function-in-chrome-but-not-ff/30159029#30159029). +1 for noticing this.

Comment: @Drakes I did the same thing...started a question a few minutes after you did and had to delete it as it was pretty much a duplicate. I'm still not understanding why throws error in IE also after answer from Arun P Johhny about IE global