# Why is 'event' available globally in Chrome but not Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, global, jquery-events

While working on an answer for another question, a strange bug came up related to the `event` object being available in an anonymous function without being passed in. In Chrome the below works fine, but Firefox throws an error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event);
  });
});
```

**Chrome:**

[image]

**FireFox:**

> ReferenceError: event is not defined

---

It is already known that

```
$("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function(event) { .. }
```

works in both browsers. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/73f2d3ut/9/) is the offending code. Is this a bug with Chrome or Firefox, or intended behavior by both browsers? Which browser is right?

Comment: You probably meant `$("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function(event) {`, didn't you?

Comment: Also note I see same error in IE10

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In IE, the event object [was a global object](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_03.htm#jscript4-CHP-19-SECT-3.2), (which is not passed to the handler function) but accessed as a global object. You can also access it as a property of the window object like `window.event`

In in FF and other browsers the event object was passed as an argument, since in FF there is no global property called `event`, you are getting the error message.

In chrome they have added support for both these features, so you will get the event object as a global reference and as an argument.

But since you are using jQuery, jQuery normalizes these 2 behaviors and will always pass the event object as an argument to the event handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#uspsSideboxTrackingClose").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
    });
});
```

Comment: Makes sense. Why would they do this?

Comment: Support a feature? I'd call it "preserve compatibility with a M$ bug".

Comment: same thing throws error in ie also though which is strange based on the global object ... but from working with jQuery so long seems normal to me

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and clear answer,  explaining about IE too. Well done.

Comment: The documentation you link to is **very** out of date. Only very old versions of Internet Explorer do not support passing the event object as the first argument to an event handler function.

Comment: Does anyone know what version of Chrome added the global event object?