# event.key is undefined - code block works in Chrome 69 but not IE or Firefox

Tags: javascript

I've made a simple keyboard counter using JavaScript. The intention is to pass the 'keypress' event key name as a HTML ID to update HTML input fields. The code checks to see if the key name corresponds to an appropriate field the updates accordingly. The code is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', updateCount);

function updateCount() {

var cellArray = ["z","x","c","v","b","n","m","s","d","f","g"];
var keyName = event.key;
if (cellArray.includes(keyName)) {
    var countTotal = document.getElementById("diffTotal").value;
    if (countTotal != 100) {
        var cellCount = document.getElementById(keyName).value;
        cellCount = Number(cellCount);
        document.getElementById(keyName).style.backgroundColor = "lightpink";
        document.getElementById(keyName).value = cellCount +1;  
        countTotal = Number(countTotal);
        document.getElementById("diffTotal").value = countTotal +1;
        document.getElementById("diffTotal").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    } else {
        var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');
        audio.play();
    }

} else {
    return;
}
}
```

When testing in Firefox and IE I get a ReferenceError: event is not defined at line 6 (var keyName = event.key;). I'm not sure why this is, can any one help? The code works fine in Chrome.

I'm a student and haven't been doing this for long, apologies if this a simple trivial post.

Comment: Change your function signature to `function updateCount(event)`. The event listener will pass the event as the first argument to the handler. **Voting to close as a typo**

Comment: Also see [Why is 'event' available globally in Chrome but not FF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30159017/283366)